# How to set breakpoint on symbols in qemu user mode emulated process?

Tags: qemu

As qemu user mode emulation doesn't support `ptrace` system call, I am trying to debug a qemu user mode emulated process via qemu's gdbstub, and use another gdb instance to connect to it via `target remote :1234`.

This works fine for some basic command like `si` to single step instructions, but I cannot set breakpoint on the symbols in the main emulated executable such as `main`.  Simply run `break main` will say the breakpoint is set to some raw un-relocated address (like 0x63a, but if I hit `c` in gdb client, the symbols for the main executable is never resolved to the real virtual address, and then is never hit.

Is this a general issue for debugging qemu user mode emulated process, and is there any way to set up the breakpoint correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug a local application or a remote application on a real target, GDB seems to be smart enough to apply a relocation offset. For QEMU however, this does not seem to be the case.

I got it working as follows:

Server:

```
qemu-aarch64 -g 1234 -L <my sysroot> <my executable>
```

GDB-Client:

```
gdb-multiarch -ex "target remote :1234" -ex "set sysroot <my sysroot>" -ex "file <my executable> -o 0x4000000000"
```

IMPORTANT: Run the `file` command after the `target` command. `target` seems to destroy all manually specified offsets.

And `0x4000000000` was the relocaction offset for all executables running on my server.

A question that helped me to get to this solution is: [QEMU "-bios" vs. "-kernel" vs. "-device loader,file=..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420670/qemu-bios-vs-kernel-vs-device-loader-file/58434837)

---

Another approach: Deactivate binary relocation by adding the linker flag `-no-pie`.